# Run a Jupyter code block automatically when a module loads

Tags: python, jupyter

I have some import statements that will be relied on by most parts of a jupyter notebook - I want these to load when I open the lab notebook. is there any way to automate this?

I'm really new to jupyter, and my first task is cleaning up and fixing somebody elses notebook - appologies if this is basic, but beginner level explanations preferred if possible.

I can put them in their own code block which must be run for anything else to work, or I can tripple the length of all of my function calls by copying imports to each one.. but there has to be a better way.

I've also had a look at the doccumentation for autoreload here: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html

seems that this is not the right thing, but should be used for safety